# How can I add this and next month to a <select> list with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

Here's what I have tried, which doesn't work:

```
<select name="mois" id="mois">
    <option value="" selected="selected">...</option>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//
    var d=new Date();
    var month=new Array(12);
    month[0]="Janvier";
    month[1]="Février";
    month[2]="Mars";
    month[3]="Avril";
    month[4]="Mai";
    month[5]="Juin";
    month[6]="Juillet";
    month[7]="Aout";
    month[8]="Septembre";
    month[9]="Octobre";
    month[10]="Novembre";
    month[11]="Décembre";
    document.write('<option value="'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'">'+month[d.getMonth()]+'</option>');
    //-->
    </script>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `document.write`
2. Don't "hide" your JavaScript with HTML comments.
3. Use an array literal instead of `new Array(12)`:

   ```
    var months = [
       'Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril',
       'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout',
       'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'
    ];
   ```
4. Make sure, when checking `d.getMonth`, that you loop back to the beginning if the current month is the last month of the year (like it is right now):

   ```
    var d = new Date(),
       lastMonth = months.length - 1,
       thisMonth = d.getMonth(),
       nextMonth = thisMonth === lastMonth ? 0 : thisMonth + 1;
   ```
5. Once you know the index of next month, you get to choose how to build the new `<option>` element and add it to the dropdown:

   - Use the `createElement` and `appendChild` DOM methods.

     ```
     var opt = document.createElement('option'),
        optTxt = document.createTextNode(months[nextMonth]);
     opt.appendChild(optTxt);
     document.getElementById('mois').appendChild(opt);
     ```
   - Just use `innerHTML` to do the same thing. A little easier for the developer, but [`innerHTML` might not work on Mobile Safari](http://martinkou.blogspot.com/2011/05/alternative-workaround-for-mobile.html). Also, if you have event listeners or any other JS stuff going on with the other options in your dropdown, those will be lost.

     ```
     document.getElementById('mois').innerHTML +=
        '<option>' + months[nextMonth] + '</option>';
     ```
   - Use `insertAdjacentHTML` to get the ease of `innerHTML`, but without having to discard and rebuild the dropdown's entire DOM. (However, [you'll need a shim to make `insertAdjacentHTML` work with older versions of Firefox](https://gist.github.com/1276030).)

     ```
     document.getElementById('mois').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        '<option>' + months[nextMonth] + '</option>');
     ```

Comment: Thanks for all the informations. Works fine... but I need to print the current month + the next month in the select list. Any idea ?

Comment: @user1080344 That's no problem. You can do that by simply replacing `months[nextMonth]` with `months[thisMonth]` in the examples I provided.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did

 var opt = document.createElement('option'),
   optTxt = document.createTextNode(months[thisMonth]);
opt.appendChild(optTxt);
document.getElementById('mois').appendChild(opt);
 
 var opt = document.createElement('option'),
   optTxt = document.createTextNode(months[nextMonth]);
opt.appendChild(optTxt);
document.getElementById('mois').appendChild(opt);

Comment: One more thing ! How to insert the value '12' for December and '1' for January ? eg. <option value="12">Décembre</option>

Comment: **First of all:** When creating the second `<option>`, you don't need to repeat the `var` keyword. You've already created the variable; you're just overwriting it. So do `opt = document.createElement('option'); optTxt = document.createTextNode(months[nextMonth]);` instead. **Second:** Just set the `value` attribute to be one greater than the month's index in the array. For example: `opt.value = thisMonth + 1;`

Comment: I can tell that you prefer native functions (probably not a fan of frameworks in general!) but everything you're doing here can be coded more concisely and readably by using jQuery, which the questioner indicated was fine. If they wanted to avoid jQuery that's one thing, but if they're already using it this approach is pretty crufty and hard to read, especially once shims are needed.

Comment: @GregPettit **Main Response:** Yup. Good points. **Nitpicky Details:** 1. It's a lot of overhead. 2. There are ways to organize this JS so it's easier to read. 3. jQuery would only really be able to help with adding to the DOM, which is only a small part of it

Comment: @sdleihssirhc It's too large of a framework to load if this is all it's used for, that's for sure. But if it's part of a larger application that's already using jQuery, there's no incremental pageload overhead. In terms of processing overhead, there will be a bit... but for such a trivial function (not iterating over thousands of elements or running thousands of functions) it is worth it for code readability. In other words, if jQuery is not used for anything else, your solution is great! Otherwise, I would just use jQuery.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc OK I'm going to have a try and let you know. Thanks for all

Comment: @sdleihssirhc works fine to set the value attribute with these lines but I do not know how and why ;-)  var opt = document.createElement('option'),
   optTxt = document.createTextNode(months[thisMonth]);
opt.appendChild(optTxt);
document.getElementById('mois').appendChild(opt);
opt.value = thisMonth + 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can get the the next month by using `.setMonth()` and adding `1` to this month. You can add `<options>` concisely using the `new Option( text, value )` syntax and then adding them to the `<select>` with `.add()`;

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/UmwKy/

HTML:

```html
<select name="mois" id="mois"></select>
```

Script:

```js
var month = [
        "Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin",
        "Juillet","Aout","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Décembre"
    ],  
    now = new Date(),
    mois = document.getElementById( 'mois' );

mois.add( new Option( month[now.getMonth()], now.getMonth() ) );
now.setMonth( now.getMonth() + 1 );
mois.add( new Option( month[now.getMonth()], now.getMonth() ) );
```